# Error: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968 throw err; node module?

Tags: node.js, npm

I was following  [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZMwg5z5VGk)  YouTube tutorials series but suddenly while running server i got this problem
I tried re-uninstalling node to latest stable version.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\DATA\Learning\Creations\WEB\website\tabs tracker\Vue-and-Express.JS\server\scr\app.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

code of app.js

```js
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const cors = require('cors')
const { sequelize } = require('./models')
const config = require('./config/config')

const app = express()

app.use(morgan('combined'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())

require('./routes')(app)

sequelize.sync().then(() => {
  app.listen(config.port)
  console.log(`Serverstarted on port ${config.port}`)
})
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js scr/app.js --exec \"npm run lint && node\"",
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint **/*.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "joi": "^17.2.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.3.4",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.7.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you run npm install

Comment: if your package.json is in the same DIR with app.js then you need to remove "scr/" just leave app.js there

Comment: Yeah I did that too but not working @KarlL

Comment: getting same error?

Comment: no package.json is in main folder and src is subfolder where app.js file is saved

Comment: change `scr/app.js` to `src/app.js` in your package.json

Comment: changed but still same problem should i remove cache ?

Comment: yes, it was a typo and after clearing cache it worked!!

Comment: for me I was not into the root directory of the app, and ran the cmd from outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `scr/app.js` to `src/app.js` in your `package.json`

Answer (score 2):

I think you there is a typo somewhere in your code where you imported **'app'** as `/scr/app` instead of `src/app`

Answer (score 0):

Faced this while using #vuejs and the fix for me was to delete the package.lock.json file and the node_modules folder. Then I ran npm i and then npm run serve worked well