# node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1063 throw err;

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

This is not the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63486116/error-internal-modules-cjs-loader-js968-throw-err-node-module) since his problemended being src spelled wrong, and none of the other solutions worked for me.

I am trying to create some cloud function for my firebase app and got the following error just after setup.

### The error

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1063
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Documents\firebase-functions\lib\bin\firebase-functions.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1060:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:905:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12) 
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.5.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

### More info

I am using typescript, I only changed some of the eslint config since the default setup comes with errors regarding that, and I am using the latest version of node installed globaly.

### What I have done

- Used nvm to switch versions (tried version 14 - 19), while changing the version here:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "18"
 },
```

- Initialized the app with diffrent versions
- Uninstalled nvm and installed node 18 alone
- Used diffrent versions of firebase-tools
- Initialized app without eslint
- Tried firebase emulators:start with/without code in index.ts
- Made sure I am in the 'functions' directory
- ran tsc
- ran npm install multiple times
- Deleted node_modules and lock file and re-ran npm install (continiously)
- Changed:

```
"predeploy": [
    "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
    "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
]
```

to

```
"predeploy": [
   "npm --prefix functions run build"
]
```

I have succesfuly created one functioning project folder using js instead of ts, without eslint, and I cannot replicate it. I am using the same (latest) node version with node: "18" in package.json.

### What I expect

A succesful build when runnig `npm run build` or firebase `emulators:start`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While looking for more instances of this error on other blog posts and forums, I came across [this](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-cannot-find-module-loader-js) blog post showcasing a few reasons the error might occur. Turns out my main issue was having a special character ('&') within the directory path (I removed that part of the path in the question for privacy reasons). When I initiate the project in a different directory, I could build the project with typescript and eslint configuration.